# React Router: Changes URL but does not render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

As a newbie to React and Material-UI, I'm desperated about a routing problem.

When the button is clicked, the URL changes - but the component does not render for some reason. I've tried nearly every possible solution provided here on StackOverflow. Nothing works. Maybe you can find the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom'

const Spielwiese = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(
  (props, ref) => <Link innerRef={ref as any} {...props} />
)

const Favoriten = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(
  (props, ref) => <Link innerRef={ref as any} {...props} />
)

const LandingPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Button
          component={Spielwiese}
          to="/spielwiese"
        >
          Dinge finden!
        </Button>
        <Button
          component={Favoriten}
          to="/favoriten"
        >
          Meine Favoriten!
        </Button>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LandingPage
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @RuntimeError try my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `Routes` for each of your components inside a `BrowserRouter`. Otherwise, you cannot navigate your App.

See sandbox for solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-flower-to9jd

Additionally, you should separate the `LandingPage` content into its own component. Then you will define a `Route` for that component as well.

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";
import Spielwiese from "./Spielwiese";
import Favoriten from "./Favoriten";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route component={LandingPage} path="/" exact />
        <Route component={Spielwiese} path="/spielwiese" />
        <Route component={Favoriten} path="/favoriten" />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### LandingPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LandingPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/spielwiese">
        <Button>Dinge finden!</Button>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/favoriten">
        <Button>Meine Favoriten!</Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Comment: Christopher Ngo to the rescue :) Worked so well, thank you! Is there any way to get rid of the underlines?

Comment: @RuntimeError im sure u can just css over it :)

Comment: Ah, `<Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/spielwiese">` worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot see the difference between Spielwiese and Favoriten that's maybe the reason :)?